# Why is my JPanel not showing up on my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I've included the relevant section of my code for review. Currently all I see when I run it is a large grey JFrame without my panels on it. I had one of the panels working earlier but when I would add another panel the first one would disappear.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class StudyWindow 
{

    public StudyWindow()
    {
    //create frame to contain panels
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Leitner");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    //add main panel to house sub-panels
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout mgr = new BorderLayout();
    mainPanel.setLayout(mgr);
    mainPanel.setSize(950, 950);
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //add top text panel that shows either front or back of card

    //not yet implemented

    //add middle text panel for user to enter response
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel ();
    JTextField response = new JTextField(10);
    panel2.add(response);
    mainPanel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add bottom panel with buttons and add action listeners to them
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel ();
    JButton a = new JButton("Do not know");
    JButton b = new JButton("Flip Card");
    JButton c = new JButton("I know");
    JButton d = new JButton("Exit");
    panel3.add(a);
    panel3.add(b);
    panel3.add(c);
    panel3.add(d);
    a.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
    b.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
    c.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
    d.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
    mainPanel.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
}
```

Comment: Start by taking `frame.setVisible(true);` and moving it to the end of the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start by taking `frame.setVisible(true);` and moving it to the end of the constructor
- Make sure you add your content to the frame; `frame.add(mainPanel`)
- `setSize` is pointless on the panels, as they will be updated based on what the layout manager wants
- Prefer `pack` over `setSize` for windows, but make sure you've added all your components first before calling it.
- Your panel isn't white, because `JPanel` isn't transparent by default (and `panel2` is covering the entire area of `mainPanel`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `mainPanel` to the frame. Something like,

```
mainPanel.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.add(mainPanel); // <-- add this.
```

Also, as [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) pointed out in his comment move `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the constructor. Basically, don't call `frame.setVisible(true);` until you've finished adding elements and setting up the `Frame`.